Friend in need asks me to buy bitcoins with money someone deposited in my bank account. Is this a scam?
Friend I know and trust is out of country needs money, borrowed it from coworker who deposited it into my bank. $135,000.00 Friend said buy bitcoin with it for him

It's a scam. There are many similar questions on the site.

The friend you know and trust has had their account hacked / someone is impersonating them.

@MTA dangerous distraction from the key issue. Even if the "friend" is able to confirm their identity, this is at best money laundering and quite likely fraud.

@JayMcEh You're right. The original wording (when I made my comment) made it seem that the OP borrowed the money from her co-worker. Now it's clear that this can only be a scam, and there's no point asking a secret question. I've withdrawn my suggestion.

I agree that the most immediate concern is what @JayMcEh said, that the underlying intent is money laundering. That's why OP should not get involved.

This is not a friend, they are not in need, and what they are planning to do will either result in you doing something illegal or you losing money, depending on how it's being played. You should not only not get involved, you should stop trusting this person, stop considering them a friend, and stop communicating with them.

Vague title.  Rewrite to summarize your specific money issue.

I feel like this is a spam attempt.  The OP is trying to get someone to say "me too".

That transaction is going to be reversed so fast it will make your head spin, and given the amount, the FBI is going to come knock on your door. Get on the right side of things, report it to your bank and to the police before they come knocking.

I would really like to know how you "know and trust" this friend.

This is a scam
If you've never personally met that friend just stop communicating altogether. The money was likely stolen, reach out to your bank's fraud department.
If this is a person you've actually met in real life - talk to them in person (at least over the phone in a call that you dialed to the number you've used before) and also talk, in person, to the said coworker and return the money the same way you got it (have the bank reverse the transaction).
In any case do not proceed.

There is no coworker to talk to -- that's part of the scam; scammer poses as the friend and says, "I need money, I'm borrowing it from my coworker who will deposit it in your bank account and I need you to buy Bitcoin with it and send it to this wallet address". Just tell your bank the deposit is a scam and let them handle it.

@Herohtar Isn't that exactly what the answer was already saying?

@Sneftel No, this answer says, "talk, in person, to the said coworker and return the money". I think maybe they interpreted the question as "I borrowed money from a coworker".

@Herohtar I'm assuming the coworker exists and is real. If they're not the OP obviously wouldn't be able to talk to them. Reliance on "common friends" is a common pattern in social engineering, while these "common friends" may not at all be aware that their name is being used.

Anytime someone ask you to acquire negotiable assets (cash, money orders, gold, silver, bitcoins) and then give it to someone else, it’s a scam, their having deposited money into your account first moves it from 99.999999999 percent sure of being a scam to 99.9999999999 percent sure.
I am not creative enough to come up with one in billion scenario where it’s not a scam, but it probably involves someone that needs you to say no to save them from themselves.

...and "buy bitcoin" should add another couple of 9s...

Let's take a look at this:

Friend I know and trust is out of country needs money, borrowed it from coworker who deposited it into my bank. $135,000.00

Someone just lends a coworker $135,000 on short notice? That's a massive amount of money. Most people would have to think long and hard about lending such a large amount.
There aren't too many scenarios in which an emergency would require $135,000 on short notice.
Also, is there some specific reason that they deposited the money into your bank account? Why not just put it in your friend's account "directly"? It makes little sense for them to use you as a middleman here.

Friend said buy bitcoin with it for him

He's "in need", but he's asking you to buy $135,000 of Bitcoin for him? If I was in dire financial straits, my first thought wouldn't be "I need $135,000 in Bitcoin." What's he planning on doing with it - paying off a criminal gang or something?
Also, why can't the friend (or the person who lent him the money in the first place) just buy his own Bitcoin? What do they need you for?
This is most likely one of two scams:

A money-mule scam - the money was stolen, fraudulently acquired, or otherwise "dirty" and they're manipulating you into helping them launder it for them
A paper hanging scam - they get you to send them the money in an irreversible form, and the initial deposit is eventually reversed (leaving you "out" $135,000).

Also, are you sure that you're actually communicating with your friend? Impersonating someone else (such as a friend, an executive at your company, or a well-known company or government agency) is a very common scam. In fact, pretending to be a friend or family member who's out of the country and in dire need of money is a common variant.

Definitely a scam. This method is often used by scammers. Although it's not new, many people are still being scammed

This answer would be greatly improved by adding additional details. For example, when you say "this method," which method are you referring to? Can you identify what the scam is and how it works? What makes you so sure that it's "definitely" a scam? Adding these details will help the OP (and future readers) verify your answer and learn something in the process.
